# What is the integral $\int\limits_1^3\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{2}}dx$?

Tags: integration

What is

$$\int_1^3 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{2}} dx ?$$

How do you approach solving this?

Comment: Put $1/x=t$ $    $

Comment: Then maybe a little integration by parts.

Comment: Note ${e^{1/x}\over x^2}={1\over x^2}\cdot e^{1/x}=x^{-2}e^{x^{-1}}$.

Comment: There's no need for integration by parts. Just substitute what @Inquest typed.

Comment: @BruceZenone After the change of variable $1/x=t$? I don't think so.

Comment: I should have followed through with the substitution.  It was simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = \frac{1}{x}$. Then $du = -\frac{1}{x^2} \ dx$. Hence we now have

$$- \int_{x=1}^{x=3} e^u \ du = -e^u = -e^\frac{1}{x}$$

Plug in the bounds now to get your answer of $e-e^\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method of u substitution. Let $u=\frac{1}{x}$. It follows that $du=\frac{-1}{x^2}dx$. Therefore, you can write the indefinite integral $\int \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2} dx=\int -e^udu=-e^u + C = -e^{\frac{1}{x}} + C.$ Therefore, the definite integral will be $-e^{\frac{1}{3}}+e^{\frac{1}{1}} = e- e^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

$$\int f'(x)\,e^{f(x)}\,dx=e^{f(x)}+C$$

so in our case

$$\int\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}\,dx=-\int\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx\right)e^{1/x} =-e^{1/x}+C$$

and with limits:

$$\left.\int\limits_1^3\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}\,dx=-e^{1/x}\right|_1^3=-(e^{1/3}-e)=e-\sqrt[3]e$$

Answer (score 0):

This answer is primarily for others that come across this and would like an alternative way to evaluate this integral. I will tackle the integral using Taylor Series. Using Taylor Series is a good way to approximate definite integrals if the integrand is difficult to work with (though in your case, it is not.) An example would be $$\int_1^3 \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x} \ dx.$$

Recall that 
$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} \qquad \text{Taylor Series for $e^x$}\tag{1}$$

Thus, 
$$e^{1/x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^k}{k!} \tag{2}$$

Writing out the series expansion (the first few terms) for $e^{1/x}$ yields

$$1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{6x^3} + \frac{1}{24x^4} + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^5 \tag{3}$$

where $O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^5$ is the higher order terms. Now our original integral can be rewritten as

$$\int_1^3 \frac{1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{6x^3} + \frac{1}{24x^4}}{x^{2}} \ dx \tag{4}$$

This simplifies to

$$\int_1^3 \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{1}{2x^4} + \frac{1}{6x^5} + \frac{1}{24x^6} \ dx \tag{5}$$

Integrate each piece and you get approximately $1.32106$. Notice that the error between this answer and the other answer is small because $e-e^{1/3} \approx 1.322669$. If we used more terms in the Taylor Series expansion, the error would have been even smaller.

Answer (score -1):

The following integral can be computed by substitution, $t=\frac{1}{x}$ 
$$\int_1^3 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}dx=-\int_1^\frac{1}{3} e^tdt=e-e^\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: No? I just substituted back before applying the values.

Comment: if x varies from 1 to 3 then $\frac{1}{x}$ varies from one-third to one.

Comment: If $1\lt x\lt3$ and $t=1/x$, then $__$ $\lt t\lt$ $__$.

Comment: @Bob: If you want to do that, write $x=1$ and $x=3$ on the second integral.

Comment: Yeah okay, cause i substituted back before applying the values i just didnt change, litterally its wrong, yes, but that doesnt change the answer

Comment: I like Did's boxes.

Comment: http://oi47.tinypic.com/1z1vr.jpg that is ok?

Comment: no. the derivative of $x^{-1}$ is not $x^0$.

Comment: http://oi46.tinypic.com/veqalw.jpg better?

Comment: yes, but this doesnt use integration by parts (:

Comment: so could you show me how should look like the whole solution? with using integration by parts?

Comment: @Fre4kone This isn't an integration by parts problem. Your solution in your previous comment  is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Did he is probably crying in the bathroom from getting many negative votes.

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking for

Comment: Did Its corrected;) 
mathemagician Very mature, I was having dinner
@Fre4kone what is it you dont understand? This is a problem to be solved by substitution as done in the three answers given